# Generating income of other members in family

Tags: stata

I have a dataset like this.

```
FamilyID     Status          personID  spouseID  HeadID spouse_of_referenceID    income
   1          Head              1        2          1       2
   1          Spouse of head    2        1          1       2
   1          Child             3        NA         1       2
   2          Head              1        3          1       3
   2          Spouse of head    3        1          1       3
```

For every "child" I want to create a variable "parents' income" which is sum of the income of the head and the income of spouse of head.

I am thinking of something like

```
bysort family: egen parentsincome =   if ??? status==4
```

because `status` is 4 if the person is a child.

But I am not sure how to proceed to next. I thought about using `_n` but I couldn't think of a real solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a weak data example: 7 variables are declared, but only 6 exemplified, and no use of Stata. "NA" isn't a Stata code for missing. Some engineering was needed to make sense of it. Statalist has advice on preparing data examples that applies here too. [advice on Stata data examples](http://www.statalist.org/forums/help#stata)

You can just get the totals conditional on a person being head or their spouse directly with `egen`.

```
clear 
input FamilyID str14 Status personID spouseID HeadID spouse_of_referenceID income
 1 "Head" 1 2 1 2  1000 
 1 "Spouse of head" 2 1 1 2 2000 
 1 "Child" 3 . 1 2   0 
 2 "Head" 1 3 1 3  3000 
 2 "Spouse of head" 3 1 1 3 4000 
end 

egen HSIncome = total(income / inlist(Status, "Head", "Spouse of head")), by(FamilyID ) 

list FamilyID Status personID income HSIncome, sepby(FamilyID) 

     +----------------------------------------------------------+
     | FamilyID           Status   personID   income   HSIncome |
     |----------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |        1             Head          1     1000       3000 |
  2. |        1   Spouse of head          2     2000       3000 |
  3. |        1            Child          3        0       3000 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------|
  4. |        2             Head          1     3000       7000 |
  5. |        2   Spouse of head          3     4000       7000 |
     +----------------------------------------------------------+
```

See e.g. [this paper](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0055) Sections 9 and 10 for a review of technique.

If you're using value labels instead to show status, the code will naturally be different.

The help for `egen` is explicit that you shouldn't try to use `_n` in conjunction. This is because `egen` often sorts the data temporarily so observations may change their order in the dataset.